# The letter 'n' is invalid syntax in Python?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

It was working as a variable name earlier in my program now all of a sudden Python keeps returning the letter 'n' as invalid syntax in my program.

Any idea why, and how to fix this?

```
bad_input=True
while bad_input:
    bad_input=False
    User_Choice=int(input('Which frame would you like to choose(1,2,3 represent positive selections, 4,5,6 represent -1,-2, and -3 respectively')
    n = 3
    if User_Choice== int(1):
        Chunks=[RNA_Comp[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(RNA_Comp), n)]
    if User_Choice== int(2):
        Chunks=[RNA_Comp[i:i+n] for i in range(1, len(RNA_Comp), n)]
    if User_Choice== int(3):
        Chunks=[RNA_Comp[i:i+n] for i in range(2, len(RNA_Comp), n)]
    else:
        print('Please select an integer value from 1 to 6')
        bad_input=True
```

Comment: just a note, you don't need to do `int(1)`, `int(2)`, etc.  You can directly use the number instead.

Comment: Downvoted because it's just a simple syntax error — not likely to help anybody else.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot closing `)` in the line preceding `n = 3`

Comment: You mean above, not below

Comment: Yes, I know, corrected it before I saw you comment :)